# Neovim packer - can't get vim-prettier to load by filetype

Tags: prettier, neovim

I'm trying to load [vim-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/vim-prettier) to load in [packer.nvim](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim) by file type, but must be doing something wrong. My packer config looks like:

```lua
use {
  'prettier/vim-prettier',
  run = 'yarn install',
  ft = {'javascript', 'typescript', 'css', 'less', 'scss', 'graphql', 'markdown', 'vue', 'html'}
}
```

However, when I load a javascript file, and try to run `:Prettier`, I get the result: `E492: Not an editor command: Prettier`

If I remove the `ft` part of the config, prettier is loaded for everything, which I'm trying to avoid. Is there another part of the config I'm missing to make `ft` load the `opt` plugin correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: I have tested the above config and it works well. Have you run `PackerInstall` to install the plugin? After that, run `PackerCompile` and restart nvim. Open your javascript file to see if you can use `:Prettier`.

Comment: Hey - sorry, i should delete this question (or an admin should). The culprit turned out to be i had renamed the default compiled packer vim file to hide it.a bit, and didn't realize that if you do that, you have to explicitly source that file from its different location. I filed a github issue that solved my problem.

Comment: https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim/issues/406 for historical purpose

Comment: @Hoopes you can actually answer your own question with your findings and the github issue. that's completely fine.